# 98kHz audio files on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, lossless

So my question is pretty straight forward: can 98kHz audio files be played on iOS devices? If someone has a link on tech specs I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really mean 98Hz? I'm assuming you mean 96 kHz. If so, then no, not without resampling down to a supported playback rate. If you actually mean 98 Hz (and your music collection is assorted sub-bass classics), then yes, if you resample up to a supported rate.

Comment: My mistake, of course it should be kHz. Do you know if it;s possible to get any tech specs for ios devices or some kind of other proof that it's not possible?